# Android N socket communication

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-7.0-nougat

I am having an issue with my code for sending and receiving data through a socket in Android 7.

```
socket = new Socket(IPaddr, port);
OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();

out.write(buffer);

InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
int i1 = inputStream.read(frame);
line = "";

if (i1 > 0)
    for (int i = 0; i < i1; i++)
    line += (char) frame[i];

response = line;

out.close();
inputStream.close();
```

The issue is that this code works perfectly on Android Lollipop and not on Android Nougat. The error I am getting is:

`java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort`

and it points to `socket = new Socket(IPaddr, port);`

This code is used for connecting and sending data to a wifi enabled device (the device is in AP mode)

Comment: So you try to connect with a router?

Comment: `having an issue with my code for sending and receiving data`. No. Not at all. Problem to connect.

Comment: not a router exactly. it is a device that has a wifi module attached to it.

Comment: And who is listening?

Comment: the "router" is listening, then processing the data and then it is sending data back to the app

Comment: There is a related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40987859/sslexception-in-android-7-but-not-6

Comment: I had same issue. My code can work on  Android Lollipop. It can't work on Android Nougat sometimes. Do you have any solution or workaround?